# Display only image file extensions within a Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, file, listbox, image

Is it possible to display a listbox content, with only certain files that have a certain format? like `BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff` only these files with these extensions that I want to display within the `lstFiles` listbox.

I have tried,

```
lstFiles.Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff";
```

But this did not work, is it possible?

EDIT:

**I have three joint listboxes to display the system drive, folders and its content**

```
private void lstDrive_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstFolders.Items.Clear();

            try
            {
                DriveInfo drive = (DriveInfo)lstDrive.SelectedItem;

                foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
                    lstFolders.Items.Add(dirInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void lstFolders_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstFiles.Items.Clear();

            DirectoryInfo dir = (DirectoryInfo)lstFolders.SelectedItem;

            foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
                lstFiles.Items.Add(fi);
        }

        private void lstFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)lstFiles.SelectedItem).FullName);

        }

        private int lastIndex = 0;

        private void lstFiles_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (lstFiles.SelectedIndex == lastIndex)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
                {
                    lstFiles.SelectedIndex = lstFiles.Items.Count - 1;
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                {
                    lstFiles.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }

            }

            lastIndex = lstFiles.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What listbox do you use? WPF, WinForms, ...?

Comment: And how do you load data into it? You can always add filtering capabilities in your data source

Comment: why not just validate n text n add to listbox?

Comment: And what type is `lstFiles`?

Comment: are the listbox items just strings or complex objects?

Comment: Its a WinForms, As now seen in the edited version

Comment: You can try removing the ";".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are population the listbox yourself using a `FileInfo` object. `FileInfo` has a property [`Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx). You can use that one for filtering:

```
    private void lstFolders_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstFiles.Items.Clear();

        DirectoryInfo dir = (DirectoryInfo)lstFolders.SelectedItem;

        foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
            switch(fi.Extension.ToUpperInvariant())
            {
               case ".BMP":
               case ".JPG":
               ...
                    lstFiles.Items.Add(fi);
                    break;
             }
     }
```

Comment: fffffffffffffffffffff. Beat me to the punch.

Comment: Oh, I really know that particular feeling ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I personaly have no idea nor have ever heard of using "filter" on a list box. Why don't you just add the items you want when you have the list?

```
lstFiles.Items.Clear();

List<string> allowedExtensions = new List<string>() {".jpg", ".png", ".gif"};

DirectoryInfo dir = (DirectoryInfo)lstFolders.SelectedItem;

foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles().Where((x)=>allowedExtensions.Contains(x)))
{
    lstFiles.Items.Add(fi);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have figured it now but thank again for your time